# Unity Does StringBuilder.ToString() cause the heap memory allocating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, garbage-collection, tostring, stringbuilder

Today, I heard that `.ToString()` causes to call **GC**.

And I have found there is StringBuilder, so I decided to use it.

However, the StringBuilder doesn't fit to text,

so I got to know that I had to use `.ToString()` again.

```
public Text timer;
StringBuilder sb;

void Update()    
{
     timer.text = sb.tostring()
}
```

Assuming what's already in the sb,
does this `.ToString()` cause new heap memory allcating?

I'd really appreciate it if someone gives me an answer in detail.

Comment: it believe it does allocate memory for a string, however it does it once you call ToString() , where as doing multiple myString +="something" allocates memory witch each concatenation, which later has to be reclaimed by the GC seperately. String builder is useful for those cases where you add multiple strings (or characters)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `StringBuilder`, your example is unclear? Certainly calling `ToString` again and again seems pointless

Comment: I'm gonna count time in seconds,  and I'm gonna show it on the screen in every frame via `Update()`. Therefore, I need to replace the content in `String` in every frame. But, the problem is that `ToString()` in `Update()` will cause to pile up new allocated memory in heap. Isn't there any other way which doesn't cause that?

Comment: *If* you have a memory allocation issue, it's almost always better to use a profiler to *identify* the cause of the issue rather than guess or assume that it must be because of X. Don't try to categorise types or methods as either "good" or "bad".

Answer (score 1):

As @zambari mentioned in the comment, `StringBuilder` allows to create only one resulting string for several concatenations. But still, every `.ToString()` call will result in allocation.

First of all, there is no easy way (or at least I don't know it :D ) to make a zero-allocation visual timer in Unity3d =)

But, you can do easy memory optimization. If you only need to show seconds (not accurate milliseconds), you have no need to recreate the string representation and set it to a text label every frame. It is enough to make it only when the number of seconds is changed.

I'm talking about something like this:

```
    void Update()
    {
        _elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        int secondsToShow = (int)_elapsed;
        if (secondsToShow != _prevShownSeconds)
        {
            _prevShownSeconds = secondsToShow;
            _timer.text = secondsToShow.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Perhaps it will not fit your needs if you, for example, have tons of timers on the scene. But usually, it is enough for most games.

Also, you can always check memory allocations in the unity profiler window.